# How can I validate fields and criteria at execute override?

Tags: mysql, validation, orm, replication, cakephp-3.4

We have a c (central) server and several d (district servers), such as d1, d2, d3, d4, d5.

There are some tables that are to be replicated. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that we have a `tblFoo` table that exists on d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 and c as well and it has the same structure in all. The rules are simple:

- if a record exists at a d server, then it exists on the c server and has the exact same values for each fields
- if a record exists on a d server (for example on d1), then it does not exist on any other d server (d2, d3, d4 nor d5)

The goal is to make sure that if a change is made on `tblFoo` (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) for a d server, then it should be done promptly on the c server as well. This works nicely for `insert` (because the id, `pkFooID` is having the `auto_increment` property by definition). This also works for `update` and `delete`, but we have some worries about those. This is (the simplified version of the) code:

```
namespace App\ORM;

use Cake\ORM\Query as ORMQuery;
// Some other use statements

class Query extends ORMQuery
{
    //Lots of stuff...

    /**
     * Overrides a method with the same name to handle synchonizations with c
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //Some tables need replication. If this is such a table, then we need to perform some extra steps. Otherwise we would just call the parent
        //Method
        if (($this->_repository->getIgnoreType() || (!in_array($this->type(), ['select']))) && $this->isReplicate() && ($this->getConnection()->configName() !== 'c')) {
            //Getting the table
            $table = $this->_repository->getTable();
            //Replicating the query
            $replica = clone $this;
            //Setting the connection of the replica to c, because we need to apply the district changes on central
            $replica->setParentConnectionType('d')->setConnection(ConnectionManager::get('c'));
            $replica->setIgnoreType($this->_repository->getIgnoreType());
            //We execute the replica first, because we will need to refer to c IDs and not the other way around
            $replica->execute();
            //If this is an insert, then we need to handle the ids as well
            if (!empty($this->clause('insert'))) {
                //We load the primary key's name to use it later to find the maximum value
                $primaryKey = $this->_repository->getPrimaryKey();
                //We get the highest ID value, which will always be a positive number, because we have already executed the query at the replica
                $firstID = $replica->getConnection()
                                   ->execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS {$primaryKey}")
                                   ->fetchAll('assoc')[0][$primaryKey];

                //We get the columns
                $columns = $this->clause('values')->getColumns();
                //In order to add the primary key
                $columns[] = $primaryKey;
                //And then override the insert clause with this adjusted array
                $this->insert($columns);
                //We get the values
                $values = $this->clause('values')->getValues();
                //And their count
                $count = count($values);
                //There could be multiple rows inserted already into the replica as part of this query, we need to replicate all their IDs, without
                //assuming that there is a single inserted record
                for ($index = 0; $index < $count; $index++) {
                    //We add the proper ID value into all of the records to be inserted
                    $values[$index][$primaryKey] = $firstID + $index;
                }
                //We override the values clause with this adjusted array, which contains PK values as well
                $this->clause('values')->values($values);
            }
        }
        if ($this->isQueryDelete) {
            $this->setIgnoreType(false);
        }
        //We nevertheless execute the query in any case, independently of whether it was a replicate table
        //If it was a replicate table, then we have already made adjustments to the query in the if block
        return parent::execute();
    }

}
```

**The worry is the following**: If we execute `update` or `delete` statements on d1 whose condition would be met by records at another district server (d2, d3, d4, d5), then we would end up with the `update` and `delete` statement being correctly executed on d1, but once the same statements are executed at d1, we may accidentally update/delete records of other districts from the c server.

To remedy this issue, the proposed solution is to validate the statements and throw an exception if one of the following conditions is not met:

- the condition is either `=` or `IN`
- the field is `[pk|fk]*ID`, that is, a foreign key or a primary key

Tables not having the replication behavior would perform `execute` normally, the above restrictions would only be valid for tables having the replication behavior, such as `tblFoo` from our example.

## The Question

**How can I validate update/delete queries in my execute override so that only primary keys or foreign keys can be searched for and only with the = or IN operator?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have solved the issue.

The models that have the replicate behavior perform a validation as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\ORM;

use Cake\ORM\Table as ORMTable;

class Table extends ORMTable
{
    protected static $replicateTables = [
        'inteacherkeyjoin',
    ];

    public function isValidReplicateCondition(array $conditions)
    {
        return count(array_filter($conditions, function ($v, $k) {
            return (bool) preg_match('/^[\s]*[pf]k(' . implode('|', self::$replicateTables) . ')id[\s]*((in|=).*)?$/i', strtolower(($k === intval($k)) ? $v : $k));
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)) > 0;
    }

    public function validateUpdateDeleteCondition($action, $conditions)
    {
        if ($this->behaviors()->has('Replicate')) {
            if (!is_array($conditions)) {
                throw new \Exception("When calling {$action} for replicate tables, you need to pass an array");
            } elseif (!$this->isValidReplicateCondition($conditions)) {
                throw new \Exception("Unsafe condition was passed to the {$action} action, you need to specify primary keys or foreign keys with = or IN operators");
            }
        }
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return new Query($this->getConnection(), $this);
    }
}
```

For the `Query` class we have an `isReplicate` method that triggers the validation we need and the `where` method has been overriden to make sure that the conditions are properly validated:

```
    /**
     * True if and only if:
     * - _repository is properly initialized
     * - _repository has the Replicate behavior
     * - The current connection is not c
     */
    protected function isReplicate()
    {
        if (($this->type() !== 'select') && ($this->getConnection()->configName() === 'c') && ($this->getParentConnectionType() !== 'd')) {
            throw new \Exception('Replica tables must always be changed from a district connection');
        }
        if (in_array($this->type(), ['update', 'delete'])) {
            $this->_repository->validateUpdateDeleteCondition($this->type(), $this->conditions);
        }

        return ($this->_repository && $this->_repository->behaviors()->has('Replicate'));
    }

    public function where($conditions = null, $types = [], $overwrite = false)
    {
        $preparedConditions = is_array($conditions) ? $conditions : [$conditions];
        $this->conditions = array_merge($this->conditions, $preparedConditions);

        return parent::where($conditions, $types, $overwrite);
    }
```